# Matlab's gaussmf in Python/SciPy?

Tags: python, matlab, numpy, scipy, gaussian

I need the equivalent to Matlab's `gaussmf` function in Python but I can't find it.

Currently I simply reimplemented it:

```
def gauss(x, sigma=1, mean=0, scale=1):
    return scale * numpy.exp(-numpy.square(x - mean) / (2 * sigma ** 2))
```

But it would feel better to just use a library function, preferably from numpy or scipy so I can use it on arrays like x (1-dimensional `numpy.ndarray`) above.

Comment: Why would you feel better ? Your function is good. If you want to include it in scipy, try to fill a request with your code !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The closest you're going to get in terms of a library function is probably [`scipy.signal.gaussian`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.signal.gaussian.html).

It's a one-liner function though - what's wrong with implementing it yourself?

Comment: Perfect! That's actually exactly what I needed :D, since I'm using the gaussian for smoothing a function :-). Well there's not exactly something wrong with implementing it myself, but I like to stick to functions that already exist, it simply reduces code size and thereby probability of bugs, even if it's just one line :-). Plus, it makes me become more aware of standard libraries that might help on other occasions as well :-). Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you're looking for? http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.norm.html

Random sampling http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.random.normal.html#numpy.random.normal

Comment: it get's close, but not quite. i had to transform the result with: numpy.power(scipy.stats.norm.pdf(numpy.r_[-100:100])*sqrt(2.0*numpy.pi), 1/(25**2)). and even then it simply jumps to zero at +/- 39 indices from the middle (index 61 and 139). compared to calling gauss(numpy.r_[-100:100],25.0). what i want is simply the gaussian function - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_function; but thanks for the answer anyway :-)

Comment: >>> stats.norm.pdf(np.r_[-100:100], loc=0, scale=25.0).min()
5.3532090305954148e-06

Comment: the gauss function in the question is not a density function like scipy.stats.norm.pdf because it is missing a normalization factor